# Grizzly - How to send a string to the client

Tags: grizzly

I can't seem to figure out how to send a simple string to the client. Every time I try it like this

```
@Override
public NextAction handleRead(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException {
    ctx.write("test");
    return ctx.getInvokeAction();
}
```

it throws an error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.WritableMessage

I tried implementing my own WritableMessage, which it then sends but it doesn't work. I can't figure out how to set it up properly, or if it's the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add StringFilter, like in the sample
https://github.com/GrizzlyNIO/grizzly-mirror/blob/2.3.x/samples/framework-samples/src/main/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/samples/echo/EchoClient.java

Comment: Alright, then how should I set it up so I can send strings to the client, but also parse bytes in the server. My own filter does no longer receive any data (current chain setup: TransportFilter-StringFilter-my own filter)

Comment: it depends how you translate byte[] to String. Is your protocol String based? Does your client also sends Strings?

Comment: The protocol is byte based. The client does not send strings. However I want to be able to send a string to the client regardless of the protocol. It would work a bit like a second protocol.

Comment: if you want to send Strings, but receive Buffer - just extend StringFilter and override handleRead(...) method like handleRead(...) {return ctx.getInvokeAction());}